program doesn't start and there isn't an issue that comes up after I run it. While loops, myFunction() and if
I am making a program where you have to guess the secret password. If you don't then the program will alert you. I expect that the problem lies with label. I have tried innerText, innerHTML, TextContent and it still doesn't work and doesn't report any issues. Here is the code:


let button = document.getElementById("button")
let input = document.getElementById("input")
let label = document.getElementById("label")
let guess = false;
let password = "Monkey4";

function myFunction() {
  while (guess) {
    if (password = "Monkey4") {
      guess = true;
      label.textContent = "gg";
    } else {
      alert("try again");
    }
  }
}
<input id="input">
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<label id="label">Guess it and the text will change</label>




let guess = false; then while (guess) { The body of the while will never be entered.

Also note that elements with an id attribute don't need to be "found", they are automatically guaranteed to exist (provided the id is a string that counts as valid JS variable name, and provided their name does not conflict with a built-in name)

if (password = "Monkey4") = is assignment. == and === are comparison. I also fail to see why you're using a <label> element by itself. The <label> element represents a caption for an item in a user interface.

Is it a problem? Its the best option for me, because it gives information to the user and it can be changed like in the example when you click on the button.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Do you perhaps refer to named objects? As the note at the section's beginning mentions, using e.g. document.getElementById() instead of named objects is recommended.

it's recommended because it's super easy to clobber a global property if you don't intentionally write id attributes such that they won't.

You don't need a while loop at all. When the user clicks the button, it should just check the password they entered in the input field once. If you use a loop, it won't allow them to change the password.
As mentioned in the comments, you have to use == or === to compare things.


let button = document.getElementById("button")
let input = document.getElementById("input")
let label = document.getElementById("label")
let correctPassword = "Monkey4";

function myFunction() {
  let password = input.value;
  if (password == correctPassword) {
    label.textContent = "gg";
  } else {
    alert("try again");
  }
}
<input id="input">
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<label id="label">Guess it and the text will change</label>




The point of the program is to test my knowledge. It isn't made with the purpose of making the most optimal user experience and interface.

Well, it doesn't work at all. JavaScript doesn't allow the user to modify elements while a loop is running. You could use prompt() in the loop to ask the user for a password. But if that's what you wanted, what is the input for?

The while condition should be true when you go into the loop, and there has to be a way for it to change during the loop.

Your while loop will only run when guess is true, which you have set to false directly before initializing myFunction(). By design, the loop will never run in this state, and you're not seeing any errors because there aren't any. You'll need to modify the logic of the while loop check to something like the following:
while (guess === false) {
    // Some logic
}


That's certainly one of the many problems, but you'll need to point out all the other problems too =)

You don't need a While-loop.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
     
<input id="input">
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">Check</button>
<label id="label">Guess it and the text will change</label>

<script>
     
     const input = document.getElementById("input")
     const label = document.getElementById("label")


     function myFunction() {
          if (input.value == "Monkey4") label.textContent = "Correct"
          else alert("try again")
     }

</script>

</body>
</html>



